# How to Restart IE WebBrowser Control in C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, proxy, browser

Basically I've figured out how to pro grammatically change proxies, but now I want my WebBrowser to use the new proxy. To do that I presume I need to restart IE, and by extension, the IE based WebBrowser control in my C# application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using the WebBrowser Control in your C# application then you cannot do something like restarting IE, because its control you are using in your application.

But how about reloading the Webbrowser control may be a new instance, hope this might help you

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser and Internet Explorer use common proxy settings in the system. You do not need to restart WebBrowser or IE- as soon as proxies changed, it will be used. If you change the proxy settings in WebBrowser, they will immediately apply in IE, and vice versa. I hope I have correctly understood the question.